# Await all pending promises in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize, in a batch process I go adding records to the database asynchronously (each insert is a promise) but at a certain point I need to be sure all the stuff is in the database (all promises resolved)

Does Sequelize provide any mechanism to be sure of that? (I can think of some tricks to achieve this but I'd like to be sure to not invent the wheel once again)

Comment: If Sequelize returns a standard Promise, what's wrong with `Promise.all`?

Comment: For Promise.all you have to keep all the returned addresses, no big problem but I was wondering if there would be some more direct trick not needing to store all the promises)

Answer (score 1):

As `Sequalize` returns a `Promise` for each call, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all).

Comment: so this would imply storing all the returned promises somewhere, right? (I was looking if exists something more straight )

Comment: Yes, I think is the easiest solution